# Update mongo document as a whole or specific fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

**Scenario**

I have a conversation document in mongodb , I have to add messages to a messages array and update the last sent date , see schema below.

```
{ 
"_id" : NumberInt(5), 
"CurrentOwnerId" : NumberInt(9), 
"LastSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
"Messages" : [
    {
        "_id" : BinData(3, "nuC1iYTKtkGzSuv7pVHsKg=="), 
        "MessageContent" : "Hi There", 
        "Status" : "Pending", 
        "DateSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
        "Method" : "Slack"
    }
 ]
}
```

**My question**

Would it be more efficient to simply read out the whole document (using the `BsonId`) and update the document via c# as a whole ie pushing my message to the array and setting the last sent day and then updating the document as a whole using the driver OR do two calls to the database using $set and $push operators to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Eduardo Hitek said, you can set multiple properties in a single query.
So you can update the entity without actually having to retrieve it from the database first like this:

```
    //Build an Id Filter
    var idFilter = Builders<Chat>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, "1");


    var message = new Message() { MessageContent = "Hey!", Method = "Slack" };

    //Build an update definition to add the message
    var addMessage = Builders<Chat>.Update.AddToSet(x => x.Messages, message);
    //Build an update definition to set the LastSent property
    var setLastSent = Builders<Chat>.Update.Set(x => x.LastSent, DateTime.Now);
    //Combine both update definitions
    var combinedUpdate = Builders<Chat>.Update.Combine(addMessage, setLastSent);

    //Execute the query.
    db.GetCollection<Chat>("ChatCollection").UpdateOne(idFilter, combinedUpdate);
```

The added benefit from updating an entity like this is that it's done atomically.

Comment: There's no need to build a filter like that. Just add .UpdateOne(x => x.Id == id, combinedUpdate);

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't need to make 2 calls, because MongoDB update command can accept more than one update instruction. 
Example:

```
db.collection.update({_id: docId}, {$push: {values: dboVital}, $set: {endTime: time}});
```

So, you could add the message to your array, and update the lastSentDay with just one call.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was looking for the C# way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

like the other answers say, you can do it in a single mongodb command with the help of either $push or $addToSet. here's how to do it in a convenient and strongly typed manner using my library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities)

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Conversation : Entity
        {
            public DateTime LastSent { get; set; }
            public Message[] Messages { get; set; }
        }

        public class Message
        {
            public string Content { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var convo = new Conversation
            {
                LastSent = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10),
                Messages = new[] { new Message { Content = "This is the first message..." } }
            };
            convo.Save();

            var msg = new Message { Content = "This is a new message..." };

            DB.Update<Conversation>()
              .Match(c => c.ID == convo.ID)
              .Modify(c => c.LastSent, DateTime.Now)
              .Modify(b => b.Push(c => c.Messages, msg))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

the following update command is sent to the database:

```java
db.Conversation.update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d0ce23647e2d210903b3930")
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "LastSent": ISODate("2019-06-21T13:57:10.998Z")
        },
        "$push": {
            "Messages": {
                "Content": "This is a new message..."
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "multi": true,
        "upsert": false
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I took a look over your library and I LOVE it. While I cant use it yet I would like to know if this (entity framework) like approach would allow a unit of work pattern?

Comment: @cl0ud i believe so... with proper use of [multi-document transactions](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/6.-Transactions) you can build your own unit-of-work classes. also you can build your own repositories, services, managers, etc. by wrapping up the library methods if you need to isolate the mongodb logic from your business logic. however, if your projects are small to medium in size and you don't hope to switch db technologies in the future, you don't need all that middle-men because the library is basically a generic repository and you can use it directly.